# PowerShell and ffmpeg or similar commands

Tags: powershell

I want to loop through all the files or in this specific case all the .mp4 files.

For each of the mp4 files I want to run the ffmpeg command.

something like this...

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -i  $file -c copy -map 0:v? -map 0:a? $filenew
```

My problem is this... the `$filenew` doesn't seem to have any value, and ffmpeg needs a new file name.   It seems to read in `$file` ok... but hates it when I try to give it the output file.. Something easy I am sure and I am just missing it..

Here is what I have so far.. not matter what I do.. `$filenew` is blank.. so it trys to reuse the `$file` name

```
foreach ($file in $files){
  .\ffmpeg.exe -i  $file -c copy -map 0:v? -map 0:a? $filenew
}
```

Output:

```
  Stream #0:5[0x0]: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 720x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:3], 90k tbr, 90k tbn (attached pic)
  Stream #0:6[0x6](und): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-06-07T00:38:01.000000Z
File 'American Gangster.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
```

Comment: Well, what _would_ you like to name the output file? Use a random string? Original name + some suffix? Or do you just want to overwrite the original file without being prompted?

Comment: From the code you've provided you haven't defined `$filenew` anywhere.  You need to do so.

Comment: I would like to add something liked fixed to the front of the name.. or the end of the name.. I really don't care as long as I can tell what is the new file vs the origina....    I also agree I forgot to add the line of code to  try and define tne $filenew.. that was an oversight.... but not matter what I tried ffmpeg didn't seem to see $filenew.  I have tried things like $filenew=$files +"fixed" and several other iterations.. no joy.. new to powershell and not sure how to manipulate variables like this.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi Guys.... I did get it to work finally.. not sure why I was having such a hard time with the new file name...Guess I was tired.. brain fart?  or?  solar flares? lol.    I got it working with..                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                      
 dir *.mp4 | foreach-object { $newname = (get-item $_ ).name ; .\ffmpeg.exe -i "$_" -c copy -map 0:v? -map 0:a? ./fixed/$newname}

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with a new name.. but then I decided to just write the file to a new dir..

Here is the code I used..

```
'dir *.mp4 | foreach-object { $newname = (get-item $_ ).name ; .\ffmpeg.exe -i "$_" -c copy -map 0:v? -map 0:a? ./fixed/$newname}'
```